# Upper bound for area of polygons

Tags: geometry, estimation, area

is there a formula for an upper bound for the area of a polygon, knowing the length of its edges? In the ideal situation, the answer would be a function $f_n(l_1,l_2,\dots,l_n)$ of the edges lengths (the number $n$ of edges is fixed).

In a less ideal situation, the answer would be a function $g_n(p)$ of the perimeter (one function for every parameter $n$) which give a better estimation than the isoperimetric inequality (cf. example below).

Isoperimetric inequality is not ideal as the following example shows: consider all parallelograms with sides $1$ and $a$. Then the maximum of area is $a$, obtained for the rectangle. But the isoperimetric inequality only gives $A\leqslant \frac{p^2}{4\pi}=\frac{(a+1)^2}{\pi}$.

Edit: by polygons, I mean convex polygons. But if there exists a formula for the convex and nonconvex case, it will be fine for me (I guess that nonconvex polygons tend to have a smaller area than convex ones).

Comment: The lower bound is obviously nonnegative. Take the limit of all the side lengths to $0$ (the lowest possible side length), and find the area. For any polygon, this is $0$. So, the lower bound goes to $0$ as the side lengths get smaller.

Comment: In the first paragraph you ask for a *lower* bound on the area in terms of the side lengths; but in your third paragraph you give an example of an *upper* bound on the area in terms of the side lengths. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Greg Martin: I want an upper bound. Think you for noticing that mistake. The lower bound is clearly zero: keeping the length of the sides fixed, we can move the sides to obtain an oval shape with area as small as we want.

Comment: This seems to be a hard problem even for [cyclic polygons](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPolygon.html) (those whose vertices lie on a circle).